# What will a router do receiving a multicast IP packet with no multicast routing protocols enabled in it?

Tags: router, multicast

Have anybody seen what a router having no multicast routing protocols enabled will do when it receives multicast data ?

will it ignore ?

Will it consider it as like any other unicast data ?

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's operating as a switch or running a local process listening for that specific multicast address, it will ignore it.